# Multiple ids while still having the same "lower" classes?

Tags: css

So I've currently got this CSS:

```
#node_249 .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
float: none;
}
```

I would like to have it also affect the id #news-in-the-news.

Would

```
#node_249, #news-in-the-news .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
float: none;
}
```

Be the correct construction for that, or do I have to have

```
#node_249 .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
float: none;
}
```

and

```
#news-in-the-news .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have that like this :

```
#node_249 .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item,
#news-in-the-news .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
  float: none;
}
```

Or you can assign the same `class name` on both id:

```
.equal .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
   float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not so DRY, but I know only this solution:

```
#node_249 .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item,
#news-in-the-news .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This selects a specific node **UNDER** #node_249:

```
#node_249 .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item
```

To add a different selector, separate them by a comma:

```
#news-in-the-news, #node_249 .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item
```

If you need both sub-sections, you need to add the entire selector to both, separated by a comma:

```
#node_249 .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item, #news-in-the-news .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item
```

Answer (score 0):

you just join the lats two solutions in:

```
#node_249 .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item,
#news-in-the-news .container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
  float: none;
}
```